# Java implementation of spell-checking algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, homework, hash-map

This little program was written for an assignment in a data structures and algorithms class. I'll just note the basic requirements:

> Given an inputted string, the program should check to see if it exists
>   in a dictionary of correctly spelled words. If not, it should return a
>   list of words that are obtainable by:
>
> - adding any character to the beginning or end of the inputted string
> - removing any single character from the inputted string
> - swapping any two adjacent characters in the string

The primary data structure is embodied in the `Dictionary` class, which is my implementation of a separately-chaining hash list, and the important algorithms are found in the `charAppended()`, `charMissing()` and `charsSwapped()` methods.

Everything works as expected - I'm just looking for tips about anything that can be done more cleanly, efficiently or better aligned with best practices.

**SpellCheck.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpellCheck {

    private Dictionary dict;
    final static String filePath = "d:/desktop/words.txt";
    final static char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    SpellCheck() {
        dict = new Dictionary();
        dict.build(filePath);

    }

    void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        String input;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\n-------Enter a word: ");
            input = scan.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            if (dict.contains(input)) {
                System.out.println("\n" + input + " is spelled correctly");
            } else {
                System.out.print("is not spelled correctly, ");
                System.out.println(printSuggestions(input));
            }
        }
    }

    String printSuggestions(String input) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<String> print = makeSuggestions(input);
        if (print.size() == 0) {
            return "and I have no idea what word you could mean.\n";
        }
        sb.append("perhaps you meant:\n");
        for (String s : print) {
            sb.append("\n  -" + s);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private ArrayList<String> makeSuggestions(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        toReturn.addAll(charAppended(input));
        toReturn.addAll(charMissing(input));
        toReturn.addAll(charsSwapped(input));
        return toReturn;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> charAppended(String input) { 
        ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char c : alphabet) {
            String atFront = c + input;
            String atBack = input + c;
            if (dict.contains(atFront)) {
                toReturn.add(atFront);
            }
            if (dict.contains(atBack)) {
                toReturn.add(atBack);
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> charMissing(String input) {   
        ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();

        int len = input.length() - 1;
        //try removing char from the front
        if (dict.contains(input.substring(1))) {
            toReturn.add(input.substring(1));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            //try removing each char between (not including) the first and last
            String working = input.substring(0, i);
            working = working.concat(input.substring((i + 1), input.length()));
            if (dict.contains(working)) {
                toReturn.add(working);
            }
        }
        if (dict.contains(input.substring(0, len))) {
            toReturn.add(input.substring(0, len));
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> charsSwapped(String input) {   
        ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
            String working = input.substring(0, i);// System.out.println("    0:" + working);
            working = working + input.charAt(i + 1);  //System.out.println("    1:" + working);
            working = working + input.charAt(i); //System.out.println("    2:" + working);
            working = working.concat(input.substring((i + 2)));//System.out.println("    FIN:" + working); 
            if (dict.contains(working)) {
                toReturn.add(working);
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpellCheck sc = new SpellCheck();
        sc.run();
    }

}
```

**Dictionary.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException; 

public class Dictionary {
    private int M = 1319; //prime number
    final private Bucket[] array;
    public Dictionary() {
        this.M = M;

        array = new Bucket[M];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            array[i] = new Bucket();
        }
    }

    private int hash(String key) {
        return (key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff) % M;
    }

    //call hash() to decide which bucket to put it in, do it.
    public void add(String key) {
        array[hash(key)].put(key);
    }

    //call hash() to find what bucket it's in, get it from that bucket. 
    public boolean contains(String input) {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        return array[hash(input)].get(input);
    }

    public void build(String filePath) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //this method is used in my unit tests
    public String[] getRandomEntries(int num){
        String[] toRet = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            //pick a random bucket, go out a random number 
            Node n = array[(int)Math.random()*M].first;
            int rand = (int)Math.random()*(int)Math.sqrt(num);

            for(int j = 0; j<rand && n.next!= null; j++) n = n.next;
            toRet[i]=n.word;


        }
        return toRet;
    }

    class Bucket {

        private Node first;

        public boolean get(String in) {         //return key true if key exists
            Node next = first;
            while (next != null) {
                if (next.word.equals(in)) {
                    return true;
                }
                next = next.next;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void put(String key) {
            for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next) {
                if (key.equals(curr.word)) {
                    return;                     //search hit: return
                }
            }
            first = new Node(key, first); //search miss: add new node
        }

        class Node {

            String word;
            Node next;

            public Node(String key, Node next) {
                this.word = key;
                this.next = next;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to replace the LinkedList with TernarySearchTries for dictionary skeleton.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**General**

Many of the variable names lack meaning and are inconsistent. I cover some of them specifically below, but for example `print` is not a good choice for a list of suggestions--even though you intend to print them. Instead, `suggestions` clearly identifies what the list holds.

Learn to use JavaDoc for documenting public classes and methods. Not only is it nicer to read than one-liners, developing this habit early will demonstrate your goal to become a professional engineer (if that's the case).

```
/**
 * Adds the key to this dictionary if not already present.
 *
 * @param key hash determines the bucket to receive it
 */
public void add(String key) { ... }

/**
 * Determines if the key is present in this dictionary.
 *
 * @param key hash determines the bucket to search
 * @return true if key is present
 */
public boolean contains(String input) { ... }
```

**SpellCheck**

You make a good effort at breaking up the methods and separating concerns, but I would take it a step further. The methods that build alternate spellings should not be responsible for checking the dictionary. Instead, combine all misspellings into a single list and search the dictionary in one place. This also allows you to remove duplicates and avoid wasted lookups.

I would also completely separate all output, possibly to a new UI class to allow reuse. You did pretty well here, but `printSuggestions` should receive the list of suggestions instead of calling `makeSuggestions` itself.

```
    private void printStatusAndSuggestions(String input) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(input);
        if (dict.contains(input) {
            System.out.println(" is spelled correctly.");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" is not spelled correctly,");
            printSuggestions(suggest(input));
        }
    }

    private void printSuggestions(Set<String> suggestions) {
        if (suggestions.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(" and I have no idea what word you could mean."
        } else {
            ... print them ...
        }
    }

    private Set<String> suggest(String input) {
        Set<String> suggestions = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> alternates = makeAlternates(input);
        for (String alternate : alternates) {
            if (dict.contains(alternate) {
                suggestions.add(alternate);
            }
        }
        return suggestions;
    }
```

If `Dictionary` implemented the `Set` interface, you could use the built-in intersection method to do the lookups for you.

```
private Set<String> suggest(String input) {
    return makeAlternates(input).retainAll(dict);
}
```

- `input.equals("")` is better expressed as `input.isEmpty()`. You may want to trim the input to remove leading/trailing spaces: `input = scan.nextLine().trim();`
- This applies similarly to `ArrayList`: `print.isEmpty()` instead of `print.size() == 0`.
- `pringSuggestions` creates a `StringBuilder` needlessly when there are no suggestions.
- You use two different methods of concatenating strings when building suggestions: an implicit `StringBuilder` and `String.concat`. Both are fine in different circumstances (though I confess that I've never used the latter), but make sure you combine all the concatenations in one statement. Breaking them across statements uses a new builder for each statement. `charsSwapped` is especially egregious requiring three for each suggestion instead of one.

  ```
  String working = input.substring(0, i)
          + input.charAt(i + 1);
          + input.charAt(i);
          + input.substring(i + 2);
  ```

**Dictionary**

- Turn `M` into a constant. As it stands, you're initializing the field to `1319` and then reassigning it to itself in the constructor. Perhaps `BUCKET_COUNT` is a better name.

  Alternatively, add a constructor that takes the value as a parameter. While we're at it, how about `buckets` in place of the very generic name `array`? It's rarely a good idea to name a primitive variable based solely on its type.

  ```
  public static final int DEFAULT_BUCKET_COUNT = 1319;

  private final bucketCount;
  private final Bucket[] buckets;

  public Dictionary() {
      this(DEFAULT_BUCKET_COUNT);
  }

  public Dictionary(int bucketCount) {
      this.bucketCount = bucketCount;
      ... create empty buckets ...
  }
  ```

**Bucket/Node**

- Both of these can be static since they don't access the outer classes' members.
- You don't really need `Bucket` and may consider rewriting the code to remove it to see the difference. It's not a huge improvement but may simplify the code.
- As with `Dictionary`, `add` and `contains` make more sense than `put` and `get`.
- Be consistent with naming across methods. In `Bucket`, `get` takes `in` while `put` takes `key`, but `in` and `key` represent the same things and as such should use the same name: `key`. Also, stick with `curr` to avoid confusion with `Node.next`.
- @Czippers nailed this one: `get` and `put` should use the same looping construct since they're both walking the list in order and possibly stopping at some point.

Answer (score 6):

1. Take a wrongly spelled word as input.
2. Store the list of English words along with their frequencies in a text file. I have used [this](http://norvig.com/google-books-common-words.txt) text file  from Norvig’s post.
3. Insert all the available English words(stored in the text file) along with their frequencies (*measure of how frequently a word is used in English language*) in a Ternary Search Tree.
4. Now traverse along the Ternary Search Tree

   - For each word encountered in the Ternary Search Tree, calculate its  Levenshtein Distance from the wrongly spelled word.
   - if Levenshtein Distance <= 3, store the word in a Priority Queue.
   - If two words have same edit distance, the one with higher frequency is grater.

     5. Print the top 10 items from Priority Queue.

You can see the whole code on [github](http://github.com/amarjeetanandsingh/spell_correct).

Comment: I really want to thank you, this answer is way better than the previous one.

Comment: I don't think this solution answers the question at all. This is arguably a better spell check method, but not the one that the problem was trying to solve.

Comment: Jaro-Winkler is better than Levenshtein for performance and also it puts more weight on the prefix; most people get the first letter right, and mess up in the middle.

Answer (score -2):

Other than in the Bucket.get() method, you can replace the while loop with a for loop like in put(), it looks good!  You might want to combine Dictionary.printSuggestions() and Dictionary.makeSuggestions() because that was a little weird.  But if you want to be super OO, then good for you!

If this is for a class, you can look like a pro by replacing:

```
System.out.println("\n" + input + " is spelled correctly");
```

with

```
System.out.println(new StringBuffer(1 + input.length() + " is spelled correctly".length).append("\n").append(input).append(" is spelled correctly").toString());
```

Also if you have an if statement or while or for or whatever, you can use no brackets if there is only one thing inside it.  For example:

```
for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next) {
    if (key.equals(curr.word)) {
        return;                     //search hit: return
    }
}
```

Can be replaced by:

```
for(Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
    if(key.equals(curr.word))
        return;                     //search hit: return
```

Comment: -1 Using braces consistently helps avoid errors when adding a line to a one-line block later, and replacing an implicit `StringBuilder` (fine for such a short message) with an explicit `StringBuffer` (why the thread-safe version?) is error-prone and completely overkill.

Comment: @DavidHarkness - I have the same opinion about using braces. Occasionally, in cases where it seems obvious that additional lines will never be added, I will go without braces. In those cases, I tend to place the line inline with the loop: `for (; ; ;) foo()`, to avoid the sort of bugs you mentioned (which can be doozies to catch). Would you caution me against this practice as well?

Comment: @DavidHarkness Also, I generally have the same approach to braces around conditional blocks. I'm assuming whatever your answer is about this approach to braces with `for` loops would be the same with those, but I'm curious: Is there any reason it would be different?

Comment: @Czipperz - down-votes aside, I appreciate your answer and the input it has generated here. Please leave it up!

Comment: @drewmore I did that once in a Java project for throwing exceptions from guard clauses because the editor would keep these on a single line. However, that requires that everyone uses a tool to enforce this. If not, it's only a matter of time until someone breaks it. I've learned not to care about the wasted space over time and *always* use braces on *every* block: `for`, `while`, `if`, etc. :)

Comment: Upvoted: There were downvotes due to "braces". "Braces are an opportunity to extract." ― Robert C. Martin. The absence of braces is a clean indication that the brace-based opportunities for extraction have been exhausted. There's nothing wrong with a code style that says don't use braces unless you have to.